# Send a message box to a list of remote PC

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a script in powershell sending a message box to a list of remote PCs. but i got all messages on my local PC.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

```
$PCLIST = Get-Content 'C:\TEST\PCLIST.TXT'

ForEach ($computer in $PCLIST) {

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computer

$GetUserName = [Environment]::UserName

#$CmdMessage has to be one line
$CmdMessage = {C:\windows\system32\msg.exe $GetUserName 'Hello' $GetUserName 'This is a test!'}

Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $CmdMessage
}
```

Comment: Wonder if you need to close your PSSession between calls

Comment: yes, if all message box sent, the session need to be closed on each PC. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mjolinor is right. Invoke-Command would be better for what you're trying to do. You can work with what you have now, just build the scriptblock for each invoke calls. (I'm using '*' instead of the specific user in the msg param to send it to all users.)
Edit: I just realized that the current username variable will probably capture the user invoking this command. An alternative method of acquiring the current user will be required. Maybe through AD or GWMI.

```
$PCLIST = Get-Content 'C:\TEST\PCLIST.TXT'

ForEach ($computer in $PCLIST) {

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Scriptblock {
        $GetUserName = [Environment]::UserName
        $CmdMessage = {C:\windows\system32\msg.exe * 'Hello' $GetUserName 'This is a test!'}

        $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Enter-PSSession` for scripting.  It can only be used interactively.

If you use it in a script, all the following commands will still execute in your local session.  To execute commands in a remote session in a script you have to use `Invoke-Command`.

That being said, I don't think this is going to work anyway.  It's not going to execute in the context of the logged on user of the remote computer, and there's no UI in that remote session for the message box to display in.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `Enter-PSSession`. @A.D 's answer works  and there is a UI to display the message on the remote PC.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to tweak the script. To make a better box with space between lines. All I need to update is my .ps1 and the pclist.txt

$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\vm\pclist.txt 
$msg = ("*** Rappel ***`n`n-1st line.`n-2nd line.`n`n3rd line,`n4th line.") 
ForEach ($server in $servers) 
{ Invoke-WmiMethod -Class win32_process -ComputerName $server -Name create -ArgumentList  "c:\windows\system32\msg.exe * $msg" }

You need to remove one ` just before every "n" like the picture below 
I wish it could help some.

[msgbox and script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbrHt.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
$name = read-host "Enter computer name "
$msg = read-host "Enter your message "
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "msg * $msg" -ComputerName $name
```

EZ GAME EZ LIFE